# problem about the dimensions of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ be vectors of $\mathbb R^n$ with $k\le n$ and consider the following
subspaces:

$ M=\{A \in  \mathbb R^{n\times n} : Av_i=0, i=1, \ldots ,k \}$

$N=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$.

what is the relationship between the $\dim(M)$ and $\dim(N)$?

please see if there is any error in this solution, and correct. Thank you

sol.

let $\quad \beta =\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_p\} $ a base of $M$ $\quad (p\le n \times n)$

and  $\quad \gamma =\{v_1,\ldots,v_q\}  $ a base of $N$ $\quad (q\le k).$

let's consider the following matrices

$$ W=\begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 \\
    A_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    A_p
    \end{bmatrix} \quad and \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    v_q
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that: $W \in  \mathbb R^{(p.n)\times n},\quad$$B \in  \mathbb R^{n\times q}\quad$ and $WB=O$ then $B\in Nu(W)$ $\Rightarrow$ $q\le Nu(W) \quad$ (as the $posto(B)=q$)

by the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have to

$n=dim(Nu(W)+posto(W)$ $\quad \Rightarrow\quad $ $posto (W)\le n-q \quad$

As the

$posto(W)=dim(M), \quad q=posto(B)=dim(N)$ then

$dim(M)+dim(N)\le n$

please see if there is any error in this solution, and correct. Thank you

Comment: This is the "Rank-Nullity Theorem"

Comment: It's not clear to me that by the definition you gave M is a matrix space whereas N is a vector space. Do you confirm?

Comment: M and N satisfy the definition of subspace, M y N son subespacios diferentes, pero si creo que haya una relacion entre sus dimenciones

Comment: Consider the matrix $B$ whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_k$. Each row of $A$ is in the (left) nullspace of $B$. The dimension of the span of $\{\,v_1,\dots,v_k\,\}$ is the rank of $B$.

Comment: Any thoughts, ros?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, with the idea that you told me try to solve, but I do not know if that solution that I give there would be fine. please check and let me know if this solution is ok. the relationship would be dim(M)+dim(B)<= n

Comment: I don't know what "posto" means. But suppose $k=1$, $n=2$, $v_1=(1,0)$. Then $M=\{\,\pmatrix{0&a\cr0&b\cr}\,\}$ has dimension 2, $N$ has dimension 1, and $2+1>n$, so something must be wrong.

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean $q\le k-i+1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: I already corregi was $\gamma=\{v_1, . . .,v_q\}$